# Oracle Sql split per day based on date range and compute for total hours

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to generate this result with the input of start date and end date.  For example the start date  is 2/6/2023 6:00 and end date is 2/8/2023 7:40, it should output the following

[image]

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is about a *row generator*.

(Setting date format so that it matches yours; you don't have to do that)

```
SQL> alter session set nls_date_format = 'mm/dd/yyyy hh24:mi';

Session altered.
```

`test` CTE contains starting values (the ones you *input*, somehow - via bind variables, substitution variables, whatever; I chose CTE).

I don't know, though, where did `1.67` come from (on your screenshot), so I didn't display it. If it is a *constant*, no problem. If not, what is it, then?

```
SQL> with test (start_date, end_date) as
  2    (select to_date('02/06/2023 06:00', 'mm/dd/yyyy hh24:mi'),
  3            to_date('02/08/2023 07:40', 'mm/dd/yyyy hh24:mi')
  4     from dual
  5    )
  6  select start_date + level - 1 start_value,
  7         trunc(start_date) + level - 1 + (end_date - trunc(end_date)) end_value
  8  from test
  9  connect by level <= end_date - start_date + 1;

START_VALUE      END_VALUE
---------------- ----------------
02/06/2023 06:00 02/06/2023 07:40
02/07/2023 06:00 02/07/2023 07:40
02/08/2023 06:00 02/08/2023 07:40

SQL>
```

Comment: the 1.67 is the computation of start and end dates in hours.

Comment: @ddb20 you can use 
`ROUND(
       (
        EXTRACT(day    from (end_date-start_date))*24*60*60+
        EXTRACT(hour   from (end_date-start_date))*60*60+
        EXTRACT(minute from (end_date-start_date))*60+
        EXTRACT(second from (end_date-start_date))
       )/3600,
       2
      )` in order to compute it.